# R memory allocation working with data table

Tags: r, datatable, large-data

I am trying to load a large dataset of csv's (69GB) into R with the data table package. I am having difficulty with `rbindlist()` to combine the list of data table objects into one data table. The machine I am working on has 64GB RAM, but I am running into overflow issues, as the list list of datatable objects, `datlist`, is approximately 32 GB. Is there a more efficient way to manage this? Example code:

```
# read all csvs in a folder, create datatable
library(data.table)
datlist <- lapply(list.files("folderPath",pattern="*.csv$",recursive=TRUE,full.names=TRUE),fread)
data <- rbindlist(datlist, fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: would the `vroom` package help? You may not want to hear this, but if you are routinely working with data that is half the size of your available memory, you're going to have a lot of headaches. Is there a way to switch to a platform with more RAM ... ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563626/combining-big-data-files-with-different-columns-into-one-big-file may provide ways to do this outside R  but as what Ben says, you will struggle to do much if your data max out your ram